# Why doesn't my batch find the path to list subfolder files?

Tags: batch-file

I'm stuck as to why %~dp0 plus %%I does not seem to work in the nested for...

```
REM for each folder
for /f "tokens=*" %%I in ('dir /ad /b "%~dp0\*.*"') do (
ECHO. >> "%~dp0\_list of files with extension_.txt"
ECHO. -------- %%I  -------- >> "%~dp0\_list of files with extension_.txt"
ECHO. >> "%~dp0\_list of files with extension_.txt"

REM for each file in that folder
REM in line below, the path of %~dp0 plus %%I does not seem to get used???
for /R "%~dp0%%I" %%f in (*.*) do (
echo %%~nf%%~xf >> "%~dp0\_list of files with extension_.txt"
)

ECHO. >> "%~dp0\_list of files with extension_.txt"
)
```

If I do a ECHO %~dp0 or ECHO %%I prior to the second For it looks good, but it seems For is not taking the path, any idea why?

The output I get today is...

```
------ Folder1 name ------

------ Folder2 name ------
```

My intended output I want is like this...

```
------ Folder1 name ------
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt

------ Folder2 name ------
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

Comment: Add your _actual_ output (and put both in code-blocks for clarity).  Unrelated tip: store `_list of files with extension_.txt` in an environment variable: you're bound to mistype it sooner or later!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use delayed expansion nor `for` replaceable parameters in the *"options"* part of the `for /f` command or the starting route of the `for /r`. These elements are parsed before the `delayedexpansion` or `for` parameter expansion take place.

But you can solve it changing the current active folder and iterating from there

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    (
        for /d %%D in ("%~dp0\*") do (
            pushd "%%~fD"
                echo( -------- %%~nxD  --------
                for /r %%F in (*) do echo(%%~nxF
                echo(
            popd
        )
    ) >> "%~dp0\_list of files with extension_.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you! this was really helpful

Answer (score 1):

All the part preceding the `IN` keyword (in other words, all in capitals) in following [`FOR` command](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) syntax patterns is parsed only once and even *evaluated* in parse time:

```
FOR /R [[DRIVE:]PATH] %%PARAMETER IN (set) DO command                     
FOR /F ["OPTIONS"]    %%PARAMETER IN (filenameset) DO command             
FOR /F ["OPTIONS"]    %%PARAMETER IN ("text string to process") DO command
FOR /F ["OPTIONS"]    %%PARAMETER IN ('command to process') DO command
```

In your case, inner `for /R "%~dp0%%I" %%f in (*.*) do (` command is parsed in time of parsing the outer loop `for /f "tokens=*" %%I in ... do (`.
For instance, it's parsed **and executed** as `for /R "d:\bat\SO\%I" %f in (*.*) do (` if your script is saved as `D:\bat\SO\32634468.bat`.

Supposing you have `somefile.txt` inside a folder named `%I`, then your script (changed for the output certainty and accuracy as `echo %%~dpnxf` instead of `echo %%~nf%%~xf`) should output something like

```
------ %I ------
d:\bat\SO\%I\somefile.txt

------ Folder1 name ------
d:\bat\SO\%I\somefile.txt

------ Folder2 name ------
d:\bat\SO\%I\somefile.txt
```

Solution **#1**: use (functionally equivalent)

```
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /B /S /A-D "%~dp0%%I\*.txt" 2^>NUL') do (
```

Solution **#2**: [call a subroutine](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html)

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

REM for each folder
for /f "tokens=*" %%I in ('dir /ad /b "%~dp0\*.*"') do (
  ECHO. >> "%~dp0\_list of files with extension_.txt"
  ECHO. -------- %%I  -------- >> "%~dp0\_list of files with extension_.txt"
  ECHO. >> "%~dp0\_list of files with extension_.txt"

  REM for each file in that folder
  set "_fldr=%%I"
  CALL :fldr "%~dp0\_list of files with extension_.txt"

  ECHO. >> "%~dp0\_list of files with extension_.txt"
)


rem next GOTO :EOF command to skip the :fldr label 
GOTO :EOF
:fldr
REM in line below, the path of %~dp0 plus %_fldr% seems to get used
for /R "%~dp0%_fldr%" %%f in (*.txt) do (
  echo %%~nf%%~xf >>"%~1" 
)
GOTO :EOF
rem previous GOTO :EOF command to return from the :fldr subroutine
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this was also educational for me to understand what was happening.